# How to call a function containing Navigator.pushNamed from one file to another?

Tags: flutter

I am pretty new to flutter and I want to create a separate file called functions where I can keep all my functions and then just call them from another file. In this function file I have this function:

Inside functions.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import '../screens/productView/productPage.dart';

class Functions {
  void productView() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductView.id);
  }
}
```

With this function I want to simply move to another page. I want to call this function inside another file which are simply cards that when they are clicked they move to the description of that card. Here is my code in the other file:

Inside cards.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/screens/productView/productPage.dart';
import '../utilities/functions.dart';

class FSTCards extends StatelessWidget {
  const FSTCards({super.key});
  Functions functions = Functions();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        ...List.generate(7, (index) {
          return Flexible(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: functions.productView,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.5,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        child: Image.asset(
                            height: 150,
                            width: 150,
                            productExample
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8),
                    const Text('Product Name'),
                    const Text('Price'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In the onTap im calling the function which is stored in the functions.dart file. But in the function:

```
void productView() {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductView.id);
      }
```

'context' gives me an error and when hovering on it it says " Undefined name 'context' ". Im not entirely sure how to do this. What im thinking is a way in which i have to pass down the context as a parameter to the function but i have no idea on how to do this. Can someone please help me? Or if it simply I can't do this and i have to have that function in the file where I am using it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/screens/productView/productPage.dart';
import '../utilities/functions.dart';

class FSTCards extends StatelessWidget {
  const FSTCards({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void productView() {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductView.id);
    }

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        ...List.generate(7, (index) {
          return Flexible(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: productView,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.5,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        child: Image.asset(
                            height: 150,
                            width: 150,
                            productExample
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8),
                    const Text('Product Name'),
                    const Text('Price'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which I wouldn't suggest to follow.

You can pass the `BuildContext` with parameter

```
  void productView(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductView.id);
  }
```

and use like:

```dart
 onTap: () => functions.productView(context),
```

Also, you can just make the static method:

```dart
class Functions {
 static void productView(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductView.id);
  }
}
```

And just call:

```
 onTap: () => Functions.productView(context),
```

But, while you might like to follow this approach, I would highly suggest using navigator 2 packages such as [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).

Comment: Out of curiosity and to learn better . Why this approach is not recommended?

Comment: passing buildContext outside the UI code(widget)